# Apache Camel: modify endpoint on redelivery

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a dynamic endpoint with .recipientList(), and I want to change the endpoint in case of an exception. Here is my example:

```
onException(IOException.class)
 .maximumRedeliveries(2)
 .onRedelivery(urlChangeProcessor)
 .process(failureProccessor);

from("direct:foo")
 .recipientList(simple("cxf:${exchangeProperty.targetUrl}?dataFormat=POJO"));
```

On exception before the redelivery the "urlChangeProcessor" updates the "targetUrl" property with the correct URL, but the redelivery attempt is still made to the wrong URL.

Is it not possible to change the target endpoint on redelivery? If not, what is an elegant solution? My current workaround is a doTry/doCatch, changing the property in the doCatch and sending it to the same endpoint again.

I use camel 2.15.3

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to set the exception as handled `javaonException(ValidationException) .handled(true);`, so that camel doesn't try to do the same instead use your url change processor. Check here http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html

Comment: Setting `.handled(true)` marks the exchange as handled so the caller doesn't receive the Exception and the exchange can be routed to another endpoint. To my knowledge this happens after the retries are exhausted. But I want to change the URL on each redelivery attempt.

Comment: You cannot do that, you would need to use the dynamic router pattern, and then re-calculate the url when you detect that has been an exception thrown beforehand.

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen, then I'll go with my workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is not possible, the solution in my case is to remove the `onException` and add a `doTry/doCatch`:

```
from("direct:foo")
 .doTry()
  .to("direct:out")
 .doCatch(IOException.class)
  .process(urlChangeProcessor)
  .to("direct:foo")
 .end();

from("direct:out")
 .recipientList(simple("cxf:${exchangeProperty.targetUrl}?dataFormat=POJO"));
```

Add some conditions so this does not end in an endless loop.